# How to suppress the page reload in jQuery Mobile 1.4?

Tags: listview, jquery-mobile, reload

I have a listview page and a detail page.
I click the list item then goto the detail page.And click a return button go back to listview page.
I found when I return to the listview,it always reloads the page and show the page from the first line.

You know when I click the 100th item to read its detail then I get back, I want to see the listview I have just seen, not a resfreshed list from the fist line.  
I tried to use:

```
$.mobile.changePage(listview,{reloadPage:false})
```

to suppress the listview reload, but it's no use.
I want show the cache, when I return to the listview.  
Anyone could give me some advice?  
Thanks for any reply.

Comment: Are you refreshing the page when you go back to the list page?. Can you post some code to see how you go back

Comment: Hi Tasos,I go back use the code:<code>$.mobile.changePage(listview,{reloadPage:false})</code>.I find a way today,I add the list page property "data-dom-cache"=true, this will cache the page ,when I do not need the cache ,I do "$("div[dsid='pageid']").remove();" to remove the cache.It works for me.

Answer (score 1):

instead of changePage you can use window.location.href="#pageId"

Comment: Thank you Esha,but it doesn't seem to affect.The listview page still reload.